# Control & Tag Properties

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to write a function called `HasUnsavedChanges` which basically should be called when you are closing the form. i.e after saving the item, it should check the values in the controls against the values in `Tag` property which are in the same function, e.g.   `txtFirstName.Tag = .ContactFirstname` and `txtFirstName.Text = .ContactFirstname`. If there is any difference between the two, return `True`. On closing the form, if this function returns true, then ask if changes should be saved.

I think the right way would be to write a `For` loop to loop through the controls, but I'm stuck after that.

Comment: Do you have any defined mapping between the controls and the property names? If you don't, you need one.

Comment: when you say mapping what exactly do you mean ? like defined in the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the .Text and .Tag properties stored in the same control, try something like this:

```
For Each objControl As Control In frmMain.Controls
   If TypeOf objControl is TextBox Then
       If objControl.Tag <> objControl.Text Then
           '---Changes have been made!---
       End if
   End if
Next
```

Obviously, you'll need to replace "frmMain" with your form's name.

Comment: Perfect,i just replaced the frmMain with Me.Controls instead as it references the form. Thanks alot!